# €str rates lower than ecb deposit yield

Tags: interest-rates

I have the following question :

How can €str rate be lower than ecb deposit facility rates (deposit yield) ?
Why would a bank lend money at that rate ?

Thank you for your answers

Edit : for instance Eonia rates are always higher than deposit yield, but not €str as it seems which is lower since july

Comment: [Quality spread](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/q/qsd.asp)

Comment: No, I don't think so, ecb risk-free deposit yield are higher (-0.5%) than risky €str (-0.563%), not lower

Comment: Yes, that's the point, not everyone is able to deposit with the ECB, they who can accept deposits for -0.563% and deposit at -0.500% with the ECB.

Comment: Ok, makes sense. Thank you for the clear answer

Comment: The aswer is the same as for the question why government bond yields (e.g. Germany) are lower than ECB deposit rates: It's due to supply&demand and structural/technical conditions (as @hroptatyr mentioned)